# Declaração const no final de função em C++ e const antes do argumento no método

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, funções, constantes

Me deparei com este trecho de código em um material:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
int Bar(int arg1) const //<-- qual função do const aqui?
{
    // código a ser implementado aqui
}
};
```

**[1]** Como o `const` afeta esta declaração do método `Bar` ?

**[2]**  Qual a diferença entre essas declarações?

```
const int * ptrInt1;
int const * ptrInt2;
```

**[3]** O método com `const` no argumento, é para que o parâmetro forçado a ser somente leitura na implementação do código?

```
int Foo (const int Bar) //<-- const antes de argumento na função
{
   // código a ser implementado aqui
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Com este modificador de tipo deixa claro para o programador e o compilador que o objeto não será modificado. Os membros que guardam estado não serão alterados por este método. É uma proteção importante em muitos casos onde não quer permitir que os membros sejam alterados, salvo o uso da palavra chave `mutable`.

   ```
   class C { //exemplo da Wikipedia
       int i;
       public:
           int Get() const {
               return i;
           }
           void Set(int j) {
               i = j;
           }
       };

       void Foo(C& nonConstC, const C& constC) {
           int y = nonConstC.Get(); // Ok
           int x = constC.Get();    // Ok: Get() é const

           nonConstC.Set(10); // Ok: nonConstC é modificável
           constC.Set(10);    // Erro! Set() permite modificar o objeto e constC é um objeto constante
       }
   }
   ```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/ConstMethod.cpp).

2. Estas duas formas são equivalentes, não há diferença semântica, apenas sintática. Mas pode haver quando o `const` está em outros lugares. Só o `const` inicial pode ser invertido em sua posição. É possível usar `const` para o ponteiro e ele precisa vir sempre depois para não criar ambiguidade.

   A posição indica quem é constante, o conteúdo ou o ponteiro:

   ```
    int * - ponteiro para int
    int const * - ponteiro para um int constante
    int * const - ponteiro constante para um int
    int const * const - ponteiro constante para um int constante
   ```

   Você já deve saber que a declaração em C e C++ é ao contrário.

   Por ponteiro constante entenda que não poderá alterar o valor da variável (apontar para outro objeto) mas poderá alterar o conteúdo apontado por ela, a não ser que ele também tenha sido declarado constante.
3. Você acertou, mas nesta forma não há muita vantagem. Isto significa que o valor de `Bar` não poderá ser alterado dentro desta função. Tem a vantagem de deixar claro e evitar que se altere este valor equivocadamente. Mas o efeito é só local, fácil de controlar.

   Isto é mais importante quando um parâmetro recebe valores por referência ou é uma forma de ponteiro, afinal assim, a alteração do parâmetro afetará o valor do argumento usado na chamada. Isto é um efeito colateral e tem consequências. Em geral deve-se evitar alterar parâmetros que podem gerar efeito colateral tanto quanto possível. Claro que há vários casos que é necessário permitir a alteração do argumento, que é justamente o efeito desejado.

A chamada *const correctness* tem uma série de furos e deve-se tomar muito cuidado com seu uso. Estas são simplificações da explicação. Evidentemente se quiser entender melhor cada uso deve procurar documentação ou abrir perguntas mais específicas sobre cada aspecto.