# Como declarar um operator() booleano?

Tags: c++, tipagem, operadores, sobrecarga

Eu entendo o que ele faz e qual a sua utilidade, no entanto, durante as pesquisas que fiz encontrei informação contraditória em relação à sintaxe de um operador booleano.

Encontrei 2 sintaxes:

```
bool operator() (Tipo variavel) const {}
```

e

```
operator() bool (Tipo variavel) const {}
```

Existe diferença entre as duas sintaxes? Ou o que muda é a preferência de escrita?

O que esse `const` indica?

Comment: Pode mostrar a referência de onde viu ambos?

Comment: `operator() bool const` vi aqui -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829487/how-do-i-override-the-bool-operator-in-a-c-class

Comment: `bool operator() const` faz parte do código do projeto que faço parte:
`class CompareEggX { 
public:
  bool operator() ( APoint A1, APoint A2 ) const { 
   return (A1.m_x > A2.m_x); 
  }        
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sobrecarga de chamada de função

O primeiro é a [sobrecarga do operador](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) de chamada de função, então o objeto daquele tipo passa ser chamável como uma função de acordo com a [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) especificada, no caso o retorno seria um `bool` e receberia um argumento do tipo `Tipo`, esse operador será invocado.

Pode ser visto na [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) na seção "Function call operator".

No seu exemplo tem um objeto que é feito para ser comparado, então uma chama ao objeto gerará um booleano. Só porque é uma comparação que deve retornar esse tipo, é circunstancial. Você terá que chamar como uma função.

## Sobrecarga de *cast*

O segundo é uma forma de *cast* que também é um operador, então está ciando uma forma de converter implicitamente um dado para um valor booleano, portanto sempre que uma expressão esperar um booleano e usar o objeto deste tipo onde tem esse operador será executado esse código e entregará o resultado esperado.

Mas a sintaxe na pergunta está errada.

Pode ser visto [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Não posso afirmar mas talvez o seu código deveria usar essa técnica, assim não precisa chamar como função e terá o valor pretendido sempre que o objeto for usado em um contexto que exija um booleano. Mas é preciso cuidado para decidir por isso, há casos que pode ser tornar confuso e haver conversão sem querer. Há quem ache que nenhuma conversão implícita deveria ocorrer para dar mais robustez ao código, mas a maioria prefere a facilidade.

## Conclusão

Portanto são dois operadores completamente diferentes.

A outra pergunta já foi respondida em [Declaração const no final de função em C++ e const antes do argumento no método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79909/101).