# Quando a diferença entre "reference" e "const reference"?

Tags: c++, referência, constantes

Acabo de ver um código (função) na internet com a sintaxe `const &variable`. Segundo o que eu li na documentação oficial, meses atrás, uma referência é equivalente à declarar:

```
type foo(const * variable) {
```

Logo pensei que usar `const` para referência era algo redundante. Mas pesquisando por "const reference" na internet, vejo que muitas pessoas o fazem. Sendo assim, qual seria a diferença entre usar ou não o `const` para referências em C++?

Comment: Acho importante uma lida nisso aqui: [Declaração const no final de função em C++ e const antes do argumento no método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79909/70) e em [Qual é a diferença das expressões "int a" e "const int& a" como argumentos de funçoes em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320739/70)- dependendo de onde você coloca o `const` a situação muda. No SOen tb tem [essa aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/916193)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referências podem ser comparadas a *ponteiros constantes*, e não a ponteiros a *valores constantes*. Perceba a diferença. Sobre as diferenças entre ponteiros e referências, sugiro ler [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/7445826).

Desse modo, uma referência (”normal”) permite que o valor original seja modificado. Uma referência constante, todavia, não permite que o valor original seja modificado — é como se fosse uma janela *read-only*.

Essa diferença é de fato importante em algumas situações. Por exemplo, se você vê uma referência constante numa assinatura qualquer, é certo que a função não modificará o valor que você passou. Claro que dá para burlar isso, mas de modo geral não deve acontecer.

De modo geral, vale a pena sempre declarar as referências como constante. Assim você evita modificar o valor por engano. Se a função *precisa* modificar o valor, use a referência normal, que permite tal mutabilidade.

Exemplos:

```
void test_ref(int& my_ref) {
    my_ref++; // Irá modificar o valor original.
}

void test_const_ref(const int& my_ref) {
    my_ref++;
//  ^^^^^^
//  (error) expression must be a modifiable lvalue
}
```

Há quem compare referências constantes com a clássica passagem por valor, pela qual há cópia e portanto não há possibilidade de se modificar o valor original. Só que sem a cópia. :)