# Como const funciona na definição de parâmetros de uma função em C++?

Tags: c++

Como discutido nesta [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/79909/declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-const-no-final-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c-e-const-antes-do-argumento-no-m%C3%A9todo?rq=1), é possível passar valores em uma função como cópia ou referência. Cópia é o comportamento default e não altera o valor da variável fora do escopo da função:

```cpp
void add_three(int a) {
    a = a+3;
}
```

Por outro lado, passando por referência, o valor é alterado

```cpp
void add_three(int& a) {
    a = a+3;
}
```

As vantagens de se usar o segundo método são as seguintes:

1. Evitar o custo de copiar o objeto, problema especialmente grave para estrutura de dados grandes.
2. Fazer uma alteração *inplace*

Ocorre que muitas vezes é conveniente passar o valor como referência para evitar o custo de cópia, mesmo se não se pretende mudar o valor do parâmetro. Para isso é usada a palavra-chave `const` para argumentos de função:

```cpp
void add_three(const int& a) {
    int ret = a+3;
    return ret;
}
```

Desse modo, meu entendimento é de que a única razão de se utilizar a palavra-chave `const` para argumentos de função é documentação. Ou seja, deixar claro para você e seus colegas de trabalho que a função que você criou não altera o valor do parâmetro.

No entanto, hoje notei um comportamento estranho de uma função que criei que parece invalidar minha ideia de que `const` é usada apenas para documentação. No exemplo abaixo, o código compila normalmente:

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cctype>


typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
typedef std::vector<std::string>::iterator it_vec;

bool space(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& sentence) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string word;

    iter i;
    i=sentence.begin();

    while (i<sentence.end()) {
        iter j = std::find_if(i, sentence.end(), space);
        result.push_back(std::string(i, j));

        i = j+1;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::string full_name = "Joao Almeida Ribeiro";
    std::vector<std::string> names = split(full_name);

    for (it_vec it=names.begin(); it!=names.end(); it++) {
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No entanto, quando removo a palavra-chave `const` na declaração do parâmetro *sentence* na função `split`, a compilação falha e gera o seguinte erro:

```cpp
error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(iter&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, bool (&)(char))’
   23 |         iter j = std::find_if(i, sentence.end(), space);
```

Diante disso, gostaria de entender *i)* quais são os usos da palavra-chave `const` na declaração de parâmetros em C++? *ii)* Por que este exemplo em particular falha na ausência da palavra-chave `const`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro gerado pelo GCC fornece mais detalhes sobre o que está acontecendo ([aqui](https://godbolt.org/z/8ErqY6nG1)). Em resumo a mensagem gerada é:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find_if'
iter j = std::find_if(i, sentence.end(), space);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_InputIterator' ('__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>::const_pointer, [...]>' vs. '__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>::pointer, [...]>')
    find_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
```

Daí pode-se deduzir:

1. O erro é na função `find_if`
2. Há um conflito entre os parâmetros fornecidos
3. O tipo do primeiro parâmetro deve ser igual ao tipo do segundo parâmetro (find_if(**_InputIterator** __first, **_InputIterator** __last,). Isso também pode ser confirmado pelos construtores de [find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

O `3.` é o ponto relevante. Observando o código nota-se que:

- Parâmetro 1: `i` --> `std::string::const_iterator`
- Parâmetro 2: `sentence.end()` --> `std::string::iterator`

Portanto, um parâmetro é `const`, enquanto o outro não o é. Portanto, ou os dois devem ser `const` ou ambos `non-const`. É por isso que adicionando o `const` no parâmetro da função `split` funciona: `const std::string& sentence`. Com isso, ambos os iteradores, `i` e `sentence.end()`, serão `const`.

Um modo de reduzir problemas desse tipo é usar `auto`:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cctype>

bool space(char c) {
    return isspace(c);
}

// const std::string& sentence: também funcionaria
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string& sentence) { 
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::string word;
    
    auto i = sentence.begin();

    while (i<sentence.end()) {
        auto j = std::find_if(i, sentence.end(), space);
        result.push_back(std::string(i, j));

        i = j+1;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::string full_name = "Joao Almeida Ribeiro";
    std::vector<std::string> names = split(full_name);

    for (const auto& it : names) {
        std::cout<< it << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

É interessante notar que dessa forma declarando tanto o parâmetro de `split` como `const` ou como `con-const` o programa vai funcionar.

---

O uso imediato de `const` é o que você já citou: reduzir a probabilidade de erros emitindo uma mensagem de erro em tempo de compilação caso se tente alterar a variável: "ei, você me marcou na semana passada como constante, tem certeza que é pra me alterar?".

O segundo caso é de uso obrigatório:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo (const int& catAge){
    std::cout << "O gato tem " << catAge<< " anos";
}

int main() {
    double age = 4.0;
    foo (age);
    return 0;
}
```

Se for removido o `const`, o código acima não irá compilar. O argumento `age` é do tipo `double`, enquanto o parâmetro `catAge` é do tipo `int`. Existe uma incompatibilidade, de modo que não é possível fazer uma referência de `catAge` para `age`. Entretanto, há conversão implícita entre `double` e `int`. Dessa forma, o compilador cria uma variável "invisível" do tipo `int` e atribui a ela o valor `4`, a partir da conversão implícita citada. Em seguida, o compilador cria uma referência de `catAge` para a variável criada. Agora, imagina que dentro da função `foo` seja feito `++catAge`. O que aconteceria é que a variável criada seria acrescida de uma unidade. Ou seja, não houve nenhum efeito sobre `age` e isso contraria justamente o objetivo de se passar um parâmetro por referência. Para que esse comportamento não aconteça, o compilador impede que `catAge` seja `non-const`.